# Error: Failed to find .env file at default paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, development-environment

I recently switched to using dev.env & test.env for a REST API using Javascript and I'm getting the following error:

```
$ npm run dev
```

Error:

```
Error: Failed to find .env file at default paths: [./.env,./.env.js,./.env.json]
    at getEnvFile 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! taskr@1.0.0 dev: `env-cmd ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the taskr@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Is there something I should revise in the way my `.env` files are stored/accessed?

Comment: can you please post your package.json?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:
env-cmd **-f** ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is required when working on Windows. I was having the same issue and this fixed it.

Comment: @ElyAoun can help me on https://stackoverflow.com/q/73944618/6097074